# How should a virtual Core Data property be retained?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, key-value-observing, key-value-coding

I have a NSManagedObject subclass with a virtual property which is expensive to calculate. The property depends on the value of one of the entity's concrete attributes. For performance reasons I only want to calculate the value of the virtual property when the property that it depends on changes.

I am noticing that my virtual property's accessor (the expensive one) is getting called EVERY time the value is accessed. What is the best way to retain the calculated value of the virtual property? Is there some **built-in** part of KVC that allows me to cache the calculated value?

**Interface:**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@interface CDUserPhotos : NSManagedObject

// Core Data attribute
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSData * data;

// Virtual property
@property (readonly) NSArray* photos;

// Changes the value of 'data' property
- (void)refresh;

@end
```

**Implementation:**

```
#import "CDUserPhotos.h"

@implementation CDUserPhotos

// Core data attributes
@dynamic data;

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Public

+ (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingPhotos
{
    NSSet* set = [NSMutableSet setWithObjects:@"data", nil];
    return set;
}

#pragma mark -

- (NSArray *)photos
{
    if ( self.data )
    {
        return [self.data expensiveCalculation];    // We want to prevent calls to this method!
    }
    return nil;
}

- (void)refresh
{
    // some code deleted here. Basically, the value of self.data changes which therefore changes the value of self.photos.
    self.data = [self newData]; // not shown
}

@end
```

**Some other code**

```
// self.albums.photos is an object of CDUserPhotos (NSManagedObject)
j = self.albums.photos.count;       // triggers expensive calculation
k = self.albums.photos.count;       // should not trigger expensive calculation

[self.albums refresh];

q = self.albums.photos.count;       // triggers expensive calculation
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be something as simple as:

```
if (self.data) {
    if(!_photos) {
        _photos = [self.data expensiveCalculation];
    }
    return _photos;
} else {
    return nil;
}
```

and you'd also have to:

```
- (void)refresh
{
    self.data = [self newData]; // not shown
    _photos = nil;
}
```